# Implement exponential decay function in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am working on an ERC-721 token in which there is a built-in royalty feature, i.e., when a user issues a token, he chooses the royalty fee in ETH and he is entitled to that fee on every secondary market trade. Also, the more tokens a user holds belonging to a specific issuer, the lower the royalty fees and I need to implement an exponential decay function to calculate the discount.

```
M = e ^ (-x / 50)
where, e is Euler's number
so the discountedFee = M * standardFee
```

For instance, the royalty fee of a token is 0.01 ETH and in the contract, it will be represented as 10000000000000000 WEI. Now the buyer holds 10 tokens of that issuer and now he is about to buy his 11th token, so the royalty fee will be calculated as

```
M = e ^ (-10 / 50) = 0.818
discountedFee = M * standardFee = 0.0081 ETH
```

Can this function in Solidity? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Please post the Solidity code that you attempted

Comment: Note that taxing transfer prices is particularly difficult on the blockchain. In the real world, when selling a house, the buyer and seller can collude to write a lower "taxable price" on the transfer paper work. This may potentially require an element of trust. But in the blockchain world, seller and buyer can encode this collusion perfectly in a smart contract. This includes "holding entities" which avoid transfer altogether or "zero price" transfers with money actually sent on a side channel.

Answer (score 4):

Implementing a true exponential decay in solidity is pretty difficult, let alone expensive since the language doesn't support floating point arithmetic. This [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79903/exponential-function-with-fractional-numbers) might be helpful.

Personally, I approximate an exponential decay with a series of linear functions targeting a half-life in a certain time-period.

```
function getPrice(uint256 value, uint256 t, uint256 halfLife) public pure returns (uint256 price) {
    value >>= (t / halfLife);
    t %= halfLife;
    price = value - value * t / halfLife / 2;
}
```

Half-life in my code was the number of seconds in two days.